# A device to protect an induction motor?

Tags: induction-motor

I need a device that can protect a 3–phase induction motor from high currents and overheating.

Comment: Easy enough to buy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to protect a 3-phase induction motor from high currents and overheating.

1. Thermal overload relay - a device that is connected in series with the motor conductors. It has either bi-metallic elements or heating elements that melt an alloy if they get too hot. When the mechanism trips, a contact opens and de-energizes the motor contactor. These are widely used for a wide range of motors. The bi-metallic kind can be either manually reset or self-reseting. The melting alloy kind must be manually reset. They have a means for selecting or setting these for relatively narrow current ranges. This method is very popular and often packaged as part of a motor contactor and sold as a motor starter.
2. Thermostatic switches - small temperature-sensitive switches that are embedded in the motor windings. The switches are connected to de-energize the motor contactor when they open. They are self resetting. They are selected and installed by the motor manufacturer.
3. Temperature sensitive resistors - these are embedded in the motor windings and change resistance with motor winding temperature. An external monitor device monitors the resistance and shuts off the motor via the motor contactor in the event of overheating. These are selected and installed by the motor manufacturer.
4. Thermocouples - these are embedded in the motor windings. The thermocouple can be used to measure winding temperature using an external device. The external device can display the winding temperature and provide a warning or shut down the motor via the motor contactor.
5. Motor protective switch - this is like a circuit breaker. The device can be used to manually turn the motor on and off. In the event if excess current over a period of time it will shut off the motor.

In some installation, more than one protective method is used. The protection method is selected based on the value of the equipment being protected and the capabilities of operating and maintenance personnel.

There are other methods used for inexpensive single-phase motors.

Answer (score 4):

It so called motor protection switch:

[image]

You have to buy one with a range that spans your motor's rated current. As you see on the photo, there is a knob to adjust the rated current. This will protect against overload and short circuit. However it won't protect the motor against over temperature. For this you will need a motor with integrated temperature sensor and additional protection module. But in most cases the extra temp. protection is not needed.